# Time relay and solenoid valve

Tags: relay, solenoid-valve, one-shot

For a project, I need to control a normally closed solenoid valve and be able to apply a current on the valve only for a set amount of time before closing it again, and only once (so no cycle).

I think I could use a time relay to do so, but it seems there are many different functions and types of relays, and I'm a bit lost between Off Delay, On delay, Single-shot, and whether it is even the right way to do what I want.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have referred to a multi-function timer in which one of ten functions may be selected.

The function that meets your requirement would be B Interval (Power on).

[image]

The supply voltage is to be applied to A1 and A2. The solenoid valve is to be switched by the 'NO' contact (terminal #18 & terminal #15).

[image]